# Margin problems

Tags: css

I'm trying to get rid of some white space between my nivoSlider and a title bar that I have right underneath it. I've tried adding negative margin to the top of the title bar and to the bottom of the slider, neither will close the gap. ( `margin-top:-30px;` )

Slider - `<div id="slider-wrapper">`
Title bar (the "hot deals" bar) - `<div class="hotdealsbar>`

http://www.cheaperfirearms.com
also I just noticed that I did not specify a height in the hotsdealsbar class style, could this be the problem? (I am not at home at the moment so I can't check to see if it fixes the problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by `<div id="ticker">` with a set height of 300px.

Comment: Ahhh I see. So if I put the title bar inbetween the slider and ticker divs it should fall into place? Good deal! Knew i just needed an outsiders perspective lol